# How to pass JSON object as parameter in wsk (openwhisk)

Tags: openwhisk

I have OpenWhisk evironment in my laptop, setup through Vagrant. I have an action that accepts parameter, that is used to take JSON data. I followed the information given in the following URL for passing parameters.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/parameters.html#working-with-parameters

Based on the information given in the above web site I executed the following command.

```
wsk action -i invoke addcoins -p coindata '{"name": "coin1", "price": "3" }'
```

When I execute this I am getting the following error:

```
error: Invalid argument(s): asfsds,, price:, 3, }'. An action name is required.
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

I do not understand how should I pass an JSON object as parameter in wsk.

Comment: This CLI example works for me on IBM Cloud Functions. Are you using Windows by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I am using windows 10. As I mentioned, OpenWhisk is running on a VM, created through Vagrant.

Comment: If you are using the WSK CLI on Windows, the '{"name": "coin1", "price": "3" }' value needs formatting for the Windows CLI, e.g. "{\"name\": \"coin1\"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the single outer quotes when using the CLI from a Windows client. Try double quotes (and escaping the internal quotes). See https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/issues/1291.

`wsk action -i invoke addcoins -p coindata "{\"name\": \"coin1\", \"price\": 3 }"`